# Javascript on mobile- tell browser to not hijack gestures

Tags: javascript, mobile, canvas, touch

I'm making a small full-screen canvas game to be played on mobile. It involves swiping around the screen with your finger. I have the canvas listening for touch events (down, move, up).

Unfortunately, the browser tries to interpret swipes left and right as browser tab navigation, and swipes up and down as hide/show URL. I don't care if the URL is hidden or not, I just want everything to stay still.

As a result of everything moving, it intermittently stops recognizing inputs to the canvas.

The way I have it set up is a canvas that takes the size of the screen, set its position to fixed at 0,0. This is to prevent scrolling (which works, except for the hide/show url thing).

If you want to see an example, here's where I'm hosting it:
http://phildogames.com/scratch/sust/index.html?game=window (you won't be able to interact on desktop because it's listening for touch events, but if you view it on mobile you *should* be able to open and close the windows).

**tl;dr:** **I want to tell the browser to simply pass swipes (well, all touch events) to the dom and stop interpreting them as intents to scroll, switch tabs, hide/show URL, etc..**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve your problem by simply preventing touches on the body.

```
var myBody = document.getElementById('dabody');
myBody.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault() 
});
```

You can throw that in console to test. Tested on iOS Safari and Android Chrome.